# How to configure nthreads in dask-yarn

Tags: hadoop-yarn, dask

Following the [nthreads vs ncores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406987/how-do-we-choose-nthreads-and-nprocs-per-worker-in-dask-distributed) issue we wanted to define in the [yarn cluster API](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask_yarn.YarnCluster)  the number of threads per worker.

In the [dask yarn CLI docs](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/cli.html?highlight=thread#dask-yarn-services-worker)  there is an option to define the number of threads.
But in the [API docs](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#) we could not find the reference (only the option to define `worker_vcores`).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe dask-yarn will default to the number of vcores per worker as `nthreads` -- `vcores` is a term more familiar to the yarn community.

In the help for the CLI:

> Number of threads. Defaults to number of vcores in the "container"