# dask broadcast variable fails with key error when calculating subset of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask, broadcast, dask-delayed

I have a pandas data frame and want to apply a costly operation to each group. Therefore, I want to parallelize this task using dask.
The initial data frame should be broadcasted.
But the computation only fails with:

```
<Future: error, key: iterated_costly_function-4aff5e66b6af1c073dc2cfd0d2dbb6f3>
<Future: error, key: iterated_costly_function-74d26e42c758a8cc177047d7a0f49ff4>
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'bar':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b']})
display(df)

unique_values = df.bar.unique()
print(unique_values)
for v in unique_values:
    subset_df = df[df.bar == v]
    display(subset_df)
```

Now when using dask:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()
from time import sleep

from dask.distributed import Client, progress
from dask.distributed import wait, as_completed
from dask.distributed import Variable

from dask import delayed
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406987/how-do-we-choose-nthreads-and-nprocs-per-worker-in-dask-distributed
client = Client()#threads_per_worker=8, n_workers=2)
client

remote_df = client.scatter(df, broadcast=True)
global_var = Variable(name="remote_data")
global_var.set(remote_df)

def iterated_costly_function(v):
    df = global_var.get()
    subset_df = df[df.bar == v]
    #subset_df = apply_some_costly_function(subset_df, x=1, y=2, z=3)
    # not implemented here for sake of simplicity
    sleep(3)
    return subset_df#.values # make it return something

futures = client.map(iterated_costly_function, unique_values)

wait(futures)
for f in tqdm(futures):
    print(f)
```

What is wrong in the way I try to access the broadcast variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your function like this

```
def iterated_costly_function(v):
    df = Variable(name="remote_data").get().result()
    subset_df = df[df.bar == v]
    sleep(3)
    return subset_df#.values
```

where

- we explicitly instantiate the `Variable` using its name, rather than passing it in the closure (you could have passed the name string as an argument)
- because the data is in fact a future, you need `.result()` to get its value.